# Correct way to set dhcp in netplan

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, netplan

In some tutorials ([Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and [Here](https://arador.com/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04/)) about netplan dhcp4 appear in the following way:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   enp2s0:
    dhcp4: no
```

or

```
    dhcp4: yes
```

But in [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples) and [blog ubuntu](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/12/01/ubuntu-bionic-netplan) sometimes appear in the following way:

```
    dhcp4: true
```

or

```
    dhcp4: false
```

And in other examples it appears as not/yes

What is the correct way to set dhcp in Ubuntu 18.04 (**yes/no** or **true/false**)? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Netplan configuration syntax is YAML, and the `dhcp4` setting takes a boolean value.

According to http://yaml.org/type/bool.html the acceptable values are `y`/`n`, `yes`/`no`, `true`/`false` and `on`/`off`, written either with all lowercase, with an Initial Capital, or with ALL CAPS.

So all of the ways you listed are correct.

The canonical ("the most correct" if a distinction must be made) form would be lower-case `y`/`n`.

However, the definition says:

> A Boolean represents a true/false value. Booleans are formatted as
>   English words (“true”/“false”, “yes”/“no” or “on”/“off”) for
>   readability and may be abbreviated as a single character “y”/“n” or
>   “Y”/“N”.

So you can use any of those forms, whichever you find easiest to read.

Comment: Thank you for this reference. I was confused while reading over the documentation examples on netplan.io -- they should simply pick a convention to avoid unnecessary confusion among those not familiar with YAML (yet).

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of netplan it seems `no` as value for a config parameter is NOT working anymore.

Even worse, it seems to imply `true`.

So i recommend replacing it with `false`, which at least solved my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question when I had two servers both running Ubuntu 22.04.2 and one of them was not getting a DHCP IPv6 address.

On comparing both the configs, the server that was working had

```
dhcp6: yes
```

and the server that was not working had

```
dhcp6: true
```

after changing to yes, and running `netplan apply` Voilà! I had an IPv6 address. When it was `true` I would have to run `dhclient -6 <iface>` to get the v6 address manually, so I knew `netplan` was simply not executing the dhclient call.

Based on telcoM's answer if y/n is the most correct representation, they seem to have switched it to only accepting y/n|yes/no. After reading sascha.arthur's answer which advised to change to false, as no didn't work for them made this even more confusing.

I recommend trying both scenarios. I'm currently at netplan 0.105 (check with `apt list --installed | grep netplan`).